# I have matrix and I need to sum up all of the values around a specified row & column, including the provided position. Then output the average

Tags: java, matrix, average

I have a program to sum up all the values around the specified place but I can not determine how to determine and output the average of those values.

Matrix to be used

```
1   2   3  4   5

15  7   8  9  71

6   7  11  2   5

6   7   8  9  14

5   4   3  2  33
```

Data file

```
3

2 2

0 0

4 3
```

Class

```
class Average
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner f = new Scanner( new File( "pr20.dat" ) );
        int times = f.nextInt();  
        f.nextLine();  
        for(int x=0;x<times;x++)
        {
         int [][] matrix ={ {1,2,3,4,5},
             {15,7,8,9,71},
             {6,7,11,2,5},
             {6,7,8,9,14},
             {5,4,3,2,33} };
             int r = f.nextInt();
             int c = f.nextInt();
             int sum = 0;
             if(r-1<0&&c-1<0)//top left corner WORKS
            {
                for(int rows=r;rows<r+2;rows++)
                    for(int col=c;col<c+2;col++)
                     sum+=matrix[rows][col];     
                 out.println(sum);
            }
    else if(r+2>5&&c+2>5)//bottom right corner WORKS
    {
        for(int rows=r-1;rows<=r;rows++)
            for(int col=c-1;col<=c;col++)
                sum+=matrix[rows][col]; 
        out.println(sum);

    }
    else if(r+2>5&&c-1<0)//bottom left corner WORKS
    {
        for(int rows=r-1;rows<=r;rows++)
            for(int col=c;col<c+2;col++)
                sum+=matrix[rows][col];     
        out.println(sum);
    }
    else if(r+2>5)//along the bottom WORKS
    {
        for(int rows=r-1;rows<=r;rows++)
            for(int col=c-1;col<c+2;col++)
                sum+=matrix[rows][col];     
        out.println(sum);
    }
    else if(c-1<0)//along the left WORKS
    {
        for(int rows=r-1;rows<r+2;rows++)
            for(int col=c;col<c+2;col++)
                sum+=matrix[rows][col]; 
        out.println(sum);
    }
    else if(c+2>5&&r-1<0)//top right corner WORKS
    {
        for(int rows=r;rows<r+2;rows++)
            for(int col=c-1;col<=c;col++)
                sum+=matrix[rows][col]; 
        out.println(sum);
    }
    else if(r-1<0)//along the top WORKS
    {
        for(int rows=r;rows<r+2;rows++)
            for(int col=c-1;col<c+2;col++)
                sum+=matrix[rows][col]; 
        out.println(sum);
    }
    else if(c+2>5)//along the right WORKS
    {
        for(int rows=r-1;rows<r+2;rows++)
            for(int col=c-1;col<=c;col++)
                sum+=matrix[rows][col]; 
        out.println(sum);
    }
    else //no boundaries WORKS
    {
        for(int rows=r-1;rows<r+2;rows++)
            for(int col=c-1;col<c+2;col++)
                sum+=matrix[rows][col];     
        out.println(sum);
    }
    out.println();
  }
}
}
```

Comment: This program works but I have to find the average and not the sum.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the mean:

Sum them up and divide by the number of elements you summed up.

Comment: Right, he has to count every value summed (9 except in the edges and corners) and divide.

Answer (score 1):

As @MrUsefull said you need to sum and divide to get the average but your code may be much simpler not differentiating cases but restricting boundaries:

```
class Average {
    private static PrintStream out = System.out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /* Constant definitions */
        final int absMinRow = 0;
        final int absMinCol = 0;
        final int absMaxRow = 4;
        final int absMaxCol = 4;
        final int[][] matrix = { 
                { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
                { 15, 7, 8, 9, 71 },
                { 6, 7, 11, 2, 5 },
                { 6, 7, 8, 9, 14 },
                { 5, 4, 3, 2, 33 } };

        try (Scanner f = new Scanner(new File("pr20.dat"))) {
            int times = f.nextInt();
            f.nextLine();
            for (int x = 0; x < times; x++) {
                /* Next input data */
                int r = f.nextInt();
                int c = f.nextInt();
                /* variable boundaries */
                int minRow = Math.max(r - 1, absMinRow);
                int maxRow = Math.min(r + 1, absMaxRow);
                int minCol = Math.max(c - 1, absMinCol);
                int maxCol = Math.min(c + 1, absMaxCol);
                int sum = 0;
                int count = 0; // <--!!!!
                for (int i = minRow; i <= maxRow; i++) {
                    for (int j = minCol; j <= maxCol; j++) {
                        sum += matrix[i][j];
                        count++; // <--!!!!
                    }
                }
                out.println(sum);
                out.println(count);
                out.println(sum / count); // <-- Average!!!!
                out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The output for the data file is supposed to be 7.56

2.78

7.67

Comment: That's the result of dividing sum by 9 not by actual numbers summed.

Comment: If you want that result divide sum by 9f, f means float and will get you the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have to store and not only to print out the sums to calculate an average value over all of them.